# HOW TO COUNT() value in the same field from custom post type ACF WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have field name "amount" from my custom post type all I want is every time I post with the amount field I created through ACF will count() the field amount

ex.

```
loop
  // The task is a post in custom post type different amount 
  // the first value post ex. 10, Second post 20, Third post will be 30

  // I am trying this but not work
  $varAmount = get_field('amount');
  $varCount = count($varAmount);




 echo $varCount;

  Output expected is: 60

  // but showing 1010101;
  // how to do that 60 instead of 101010?


/loop
```

```
$faq = new  WP_Query($args_faqs);

if ( $faq->have_posts() ) {
/*
 * Begin the loop tags post
 */

    #echo count(get_field('loan_amount_applied'));
     $total_amount = 0; 
     $amountapplied = get_field('loan_amount_applied'); 
     $total_amount += $amountapplied; 

     $varCount = count($total_amount); 

     // array() = $amountapplied);
     // if(is_array($amountappliedCOntainer)) {
     // $total_amount = count($amountappliedCOntainer);

while ( $faq->have_posts() ) {
         $faq->the_post();
```

[image]

Comment: you could just initialize a variable before the loop `$i = 0; // or whatever`, then continually add inside the `$i += $varAmount;` inside the loop, finally `echo $i;` at the end

Comment: Hello Sir. Kevin Good day, am I doing right? 
... 
$total_amount  = 0; $amountapplied =  get_field('loan_amount_applied');
$total_amount  += $amountapplied;

$varCount = ($amountapplied);

// Loop begin
 
  echo $varCount; 

// Loop End
// isn't work
Reference: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/xP0lEJ7imA9
Output: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/bePFNyTUUTA

Comment: Update reference:
https://www.screencast.com/t/CS1wyJg82uMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.
Since you need to count the values of multiple posts, you need to initialize a variable with value as 0 outside your loop. and then you need to add the value of amount(ACF FIELD) to that variable and then echo it.

Use the below code.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : 

$counter = 0;

/* Start the Loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
the_post();
$varAmount = get_field('amount');
$counter += $varAmount;
echo $counter;
endwhile;

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hello Sir. Rajeev. Thank you for helping me but this time I need your a  little bit help base on your code: the output result show as normal display it didn't count
Reference 1 Post:
https://www.screencast.com/t/GyC1iWMJq4
Reference 2 Code:
https://www.screencast.com/t/p6hKjLwvWM8
Reference 3 Code:
https://www.screencast.com/t/1o5n2d9CeK2w

PLEASE HELP AND THANKS!

Comment: Hello Sir. Rajeev THANK YOU VERY MUCH I am done through your codes
https://www.screencast.com/t/KJwakj7cM

Comment: Sure, Thanks very much!